# How to skip file that doesn't have required keyword in it's header?

Tags: python

I have several hundred files and most of them have the keyword  'HIERARCH ESO DRS BLAZE FILE', in their header but there are some files that doesn't have that keyword and because of that it gives error. So i want to skip the files that doesn't have the required keyword in it's header.

```
from astropy.io import fits
import numpy as np
import sys, os

for filename in os.listdir("/home/gyanender/bin/all_spectra/Moon_bundleII"):
  if filename.endswith("e2ds_A.fits"):
     with fits.open(filename) as hdul:
        e2ds_header = hdul[0].header
        if 'HIERARCH ESO DRS BLAZE FILE' not in e2ds_header:
            continue

     print(filename, e2ds_header['HIERARCH ESO DRS BLAZE FILE'])
```

That's the code i'm using.can anyone tell me how to solve this? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A054H.png)

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code? Is it giving an error? If so, include the full traceback in your question. Is it giving incorrect results? If so, what exactly is it doing incorrectly?

Comment: are you getting a `KeyError` ?

Comment: Where's the `fits` variable coming from? It's hard to guess what this is supposed to be with just this snippet

Comment: Hi, it works properly but when it reaches to a file that doesn't have the the required keyword, it stops and gives this error ...KeyError: "Keyword 'ESO DRS BLAZE FILE' not found." So i want to skip all the files that doesn't have that keyword in its header @glibdud

Comment: Simplest way would be to just [handle the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) when it happens.

Comment: yes it gives this  KeyError: "Keyword 'ESO DRS BLAZE FILE' not found." So i want to skip all the files that doesn't have that keyword in its header. because  when it reaches to a file that doesn't have the the required keyword, it stops and gives the error. @AntiMatterDynamite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check is the header is there before printing it.

```
corrupt_files = []
for filename in os.listdir('./'):
  if filename.endswith("e2ds_A.fits"):
     try:
         hdul = fits.open(filename)
     except IOError:
         corrupt_files.append(filename)
         continue

     e2ds_header = hdul[0].header
     if 'HIERARCH ESO DRS BLAZE FILE' not in e2ds_header:
         continue

     print(filename, e2ds_header['HIERARCH ESO DRS BLAZE FILE'])
```

Comment: yes it worked but it gave an another error after going through all the files.  IOError: Empty or corrupt FITS file @fernando

Comment: Edit your original post, include a working snippet, and provide a stack trace. It's pretty hard to try to imagine all the situation without any of these.

Comment: so i used the code that you had edited and it worked fine. But it gave an error,  "IOError: Empty or corrupt FITS file", so maybe some of the files in the data are corrupt. So if i want to skip those files as well and in the end i want to print the list of files that are corrupt and the ones that didn't had keyword in the header. How can i do that?? @fernando

Comment: Edit your original post, include a working snippet, and provide a stack trace. It's pretty hard to try to imagine all the situation without any of these.

Comment: Hi, I have added the working snippet and a screen-shot of the error that i get. Please have a look over it. @fernando

Comment: @gyanendersingh I added a `try..except` to the response. Also, it saves the corrupt filenames in a list, you might want to have a look at them later.

Comment: Hi again.! I just tried it but It still didn't solve my problem. But still Thanks for the help anyway.! @fernando

Answer (score 2):

Basically from what you've given us:

```
with fits.open(filename) as hdul:
     e2ds_header = hdul[0].header
     if 'HIERARCH ESO DRS BLAZE FILE' in e2ds_header:
        do_stuff()
     else:
        handle_error_function()
        continue
```